# How to make horizontal stretching of elements

Tags: java, javafx

I don't know what to call my problem. I need to make it so that I can change the length of the elements in the horizontal "list" like this:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

I did it, but in a very clumsy way. Please tell me how to do this better, for example, so that you can easily write code for several (3 or more) elements. Maybe there is some built-in JavaFX way to do this.

My code:

*Main*:

```java
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane1 = new Pane();
        pane1.setPrefWidth(100);
        pane1.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        Pane pane2 = new Pane();
        HBox.setHgrow(pane2, Priority.ALWAYS);
        pane2.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.GREEN, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        MainPane root = new MainPane(pane1, pane2);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*MainPane*:

```java
public final class MainPane extends HBox {

    private double mx;

    public MainPane(Pane pane1, Pane pane2) {
        getChildren().addAll(pane1, pane2);
        setOnMouseMoved(mouseEvent -> {
            if (mouseEvent.getSceneX() < pane1.getWidth() + 9 && mouseEvent.getSceneX() > (pane1.getWidth() - 6)) {
                if (getCursor() != Cursor.H_RESIZE)
                    setCursor(Cursor.H_RESIZE);
            } else if (getCursor() != Cursor.DEFAULT)
                setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        });
        setOnMouseReleased(mouseEvent -> {
            if (getCursor() == Cursor.H_RESIZE && !(mouseEvent.getSceneX() < pane1.getWidth() + 9 && mouseEvent.getSceneX() > (pane1.getWidth() - 6)))
                setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        });
        setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {
            if (getCursor() == Cursor.H_RESIZE)
                mx = mouseEvent.getSceneX() - (pane1.getWidth());
        });
        setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> {
            if (getCursor() == Cursor.H_RESIZE) {
                double newPane1Width = mouseEvent.getSceneX() - mx;
                double newPane2Width = pane2.getWidth() - newPane1Width + pane1.getWidth();
                pane1.setPrefWidth(newPane1Width);
                pane2.setPrefWidth(newPane2Width);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, a SplitPane is what you want to have: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html

Comment: @anko thank you, but `SplitPane` has no options for divider and divider intercepts all mouse events, so I can't handle them. Also, it doesn't work with `Canvas`.

Comment: "Also, it doesn't work with `Canvas`". What do you mean? And what mouse events do you want to handle on the divider? Your question and your code don't show any such event handling other than the behavior that's already present in the `SplitPane`.

Comment: @James_D in the question I presented a simple example. I want the divider to dissapear with the previous node, when the distance from cursor to window edge is less or equal 10. For this I need to handle `MOUSE_RELEASED`, but mouseevent is consumed by divisor. `Canvas` doesn't change length, when it's used on `SplitPane`.